# How to avoid editing same value in a form in a Multi-user environment?

Tags: java, swing, multi-user

My Environment: Multi-user application with server and client. The server knows which field is currently in use and can’t edit from another user.

I have a form with several JComponents like JCheckBox, JTextField, JTextArea and JComboBox. The problem is that I want to control whether the user is allowed to edit the value of the field or not. When the user is not allowed to edit the field, the component is not allowed to go to Edit Mode.

For Example:
User A is editing a value of textfield.
Now User B wants to edit the same value. He clicks on the same textfield and at this point I want to make sure that the textfield ain’t switching in the Edit Mode.

Has someone a good idea where the right place is for this check? Do I have to implement a check in every single component or is there maybe a solution that fit to all JComponents in my form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can provide generic solution. Create listener `EditabilityListener`. When user changes value if component it should send signal to server and all other users should get it, so their instances of JComponent become disabled.

The problem is in concurrent access. For example what would you like to do if user A started typing in text field a second after user B but before the signal arrived to his application?

Comment: Exactly, to avoid concurrent access I would prefer that the form components are able to check on their own whether the field is currently edited or not. The server already knows which fields are currently edited, so the components have to wait for the response from the server. My Problem is that I don’t know when (or where?) the component has to ask the server whether it is allowed to edit the value, especially this check has to be done before changing in its Edit Mode.

Comment: The problem is that it does not matter where are you asking. There is no "normal" way to synchronize threads among processes, so you should always be able to catch situation when you allow user to edit the field and then discover that he did not have rights to do that. Alternatively you can make all fields disabled and every time user clicks on field check against server whether the field is not being edited now by other user. But it makes application very not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

The server can support a request for component ownership, which returns a boolean used by the client. The server side implementation should maintain a synchronized data structure aware of component ownerships. You can use a ConcurrentHashMap for example (it supports putIfAbsent which performs an atomic operation that can help).

Note that you'll also need clients to report when they release the component (possibly also adding ownership timeout in server).

Comment: We already use a ConcurrentHashMap to manage the edit locks. I just don’t know when or where each component asks the server whether they are allowed to switch in Edit Mode, especially since every component is different.